# Did the US Supreme Court's recent ruling sidestep the issue of judicial review? (Whole Women's Health v. Jackson; challenge to Texas S.B. 8)

Tags: united-states, constitution, supreme-court, judiciary, us-state-laws

The following questions and their extensive answers cover the background of the issues well:

- [How close does the Texas law that bars most abortions after six weeks come to saying 'Defendants can't assert constitutionally protected rights?'](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/69481/16047)
- [Why is avoidance of judicial review of the Texas abortion law and other future US state laws so concerning to the US department of justice?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/68681/16047)
- [Are there constitutional arguments for preventing/avoiding judicial review of state law in some scenarios? Are there any historical examples of this?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/68679/16047)

**Quick summary only:** In this case the term Judicial Review covers the ability or lack thereof for people to challenge the law by suing. Rather than write a law making abortion illegal, the Texas law enables private citizens to sue other individuals where abortion is involved, which attempts to deprive someone seeking or attempting to provide an abortion the opportunity to challenge the law via lawsuit against the lawmaking body.

**Question:** Did the US Supreme Court's recent ruling sidestep the issue of judicial review? In opinion(s) on Whole Women's Health v. Jackson, the current challenge to Texas S.B. 8, was this issue of the law being unconstitutional due to it doing an "end run" around judicial review addressed directly in any way, or was it essentially avoided (for now at least)?

It seems that [the ruling is here](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/21pdf/21-463_3ebh.pdf) and I do see serious discussion of this in one or more *dissenting opinions* but it is difficult for me to see if the majority ruling addresses this issue directly or sidesteps it.

Comment: Aren't the details of a supreme court opinion more suited for Law?

Comment: @Jontia You've mischaracterized the question. This asks quite a *top-level question, not about details*, and this particular case is so political that at least one of the Supreme Court justices has lamented the potential politicalization of the Court itself both publicly and see footnote 6 of Justice Sotomayor's dissenting opinion in the linked ruling. Further, this case has been discussed not only in the three other Politics SE questions I've linked to, but in several others as well.

Comment: I guess I would think of the 'yes/no' position and practical effects as the top level questions, whereas I'd see the details of the effect on the principle of judicial review seems quite low level. Not that I disagree that this decision itself is more about politics than law, but the points of law covered in the opinions seem a little out of our usual reach. Though I'm happy to concede the overlap between the stacks you've highlighted. Which is why these are comments rather than migration votes.

Comment: "the opportunity to challenge the law via lawsuit against the lawmaking body": suits in which laws are declared unconstitutional are never brought against the lawmaki body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did the US Supreme Court's recent ruling sidestep the issue of judicial review?

No.

> was this issue of the law being unconstitutional due to it doing an "end run" around judicial review addressed directly in any way?

Yes.  From the syllabus (page 4 of the PDF linked in the question):

> The Court holds that the petitioners may bring a pre-enforcement
> challenge in federal court as one means to test S. B. 8’s compliance
> with the Federal Constitution.